# Not invoking Cortana Skill deployed in Azure Bot Service with channel default settings

Tags: botframework, cortana

I'm following this tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/mva22-hello-world

I confirmed that Cortana on my Windows 10 device was signed in as the Microsoft account (consumer) where I have deployed the Azure Bot Service to. But when I type "Ask jthake-cortana 'Hello world'" it launches my browser and does a web search.

The last step seems like it's missing something. I found the page that explains how to test the skill https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-cortana-skill?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 But this didn't help either.

I also tried "Test Group Settings" option, not "Default Settings" and add my email account and my work account there and click Create Group. That didn't work either. I tried the invocation word on its own and also didn't work.

How do i invoke the Cortana skill properly

Comment: If the MSA creating the bot/skill is the same as the one logged in with Cortana, the invocation name should be primed.  So it *should* work. If it does not, file a dsat so it can be triaged.

Answer (score 1):

I had used the default invocatoin name provided, which was the name of the Azure Bot Service 'jthake-Cortana'. I changed it to a normal single word. And typing "Ask bobble 'hello'" worked. There is guidance here on what names to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/cortana-invocation-guidelines .